Agregar dos funciones en un tree.bind
Bueos días/tardes/noches comunidad. Recurro a ustedes ya que tengo esta línea:
tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", partial(funciones.print_element, apellido, nombre, nacimiento, tree))

Mi intención es ejecutar dos funciones, la mencionada print_element y otra más que, llamándola individualmente, funciona perfectamente (por las dudas, la aclaración). He estado dándo vueltas al asunto probando posibles aternativas, pero ninguna me funciona. La idea sería que, habiéndose ejecutado print_element primero, luego se ejecute la otra de manera automática. ¿Es posible incluír la segunda función en la misma línea?

No te compliques, crea una tercera función que se encargue de recibir los parámetros de ambas y de llamarlas consecutivamente y usa functools.partial para pasar los argumentos a ella:
from functools import partial

def saludar(nombre):
    print(f"¡Hola {nombre}!")

def sumar(a, b):
    print(f"{a} + {b} es {a + b}")

def callback(nombre, a, b):
    saludar(nombre)
    sumar(a, b)

nombre = "Laura"
num1 = 4
num2 = 6

partial(callback, nombre, num1, num2)


>>> partial(callback, nombre, num1, num2)()
¡Hola Laura!
4 + 6 es 10


Puedes también usar una función anónima:
lambda nombre=nombre, a=num1, b=num2: (saludar(nombre), sumar(a, b))

Pero eso es menos eficiente en general, obliga a crear una tupla totalmente inútil con el retorno de las dos funciones llamadas, es posiblemente menos legible...
